# Wordpress 4.2 how to sort by custom field

Tags: wordpress, sorting

Since the upgrade to Wordpress 4.2 my custom wp_query's which have sorting by a custom field are no longer working. I have read this post: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/ but it isn't detailed enough to show how to sort by a custom field that isn't part of the meta-query.

Does anyone know how I would change this query to work with Wordpress 4.2:

```
      $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'custom',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '12',
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'orderby'           => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', 
                                      'date' => 'DESC' ), 
        'meta_key'          => 'wpcf-status'
      );

      $items = null;
      $items = new WP_Query($args);
```

This is what the query output shows now in 4.2:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS xxx_posts.ID 
FROM xxx_posts 
INNER JOIN xxx_postmeta ON ( xxx_posts.ID = xxx_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1 AND xxx_posts.post_type = 'custom' 
AND ((xxx_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
AND ( xxx_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcf-status' ) 
GROUP BY xxx_posts.ID 
ORDER BY xxx_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC, 
xx_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12
```

Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php 
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 query_posts(array(
 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 
 'posts_per_page'=>50, 
 'post_type'=>'CUSTOM-POST-TYPE',  
 'meta_key' => 'timestamp', //NAME CUSTOM FIELD DATE
 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
 'order' => 'ASC',
  ))?>

  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php the_content();?>

  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, That used to work in WP 4.1 but it doesn't work in WP 4.2. Plus I need to sort by 2 fields not just the custom field.